# What is the word for "nuisance" as an  adjective?

Tags: adjectives, phrase-requests

Can anyone propose an adjective of nuisance? Or a word that can be used to communicate that sense?

The place where I want to use the word is as follows. I am talking about when children are abused and ignored by parents (as a result of high population and no family planning) and the children grow up to become not-so-constructive citizens, such as thieves and petty criminals.

What could be the word for such an outcome? 
Also, what is an adjective for nuisance?

Comment: What's wrong with a noun alone? "They grow up to be a nuisance"?

Comment: It’s a pity that *noisome* most often means “smelly”.

Comment: You say "nuisance" but that does not really carry the same connotation as "not-so-constructive citizens, such as thieves and petty criminals." Nuisance means "bothersome" or "annoying" while "criminal" is stronger than that.

Comment: "Nuisance" is also a french word (same meaning). In French the verb is "nuire" and adjective is "nuisible".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Nuisance* itself occurs as an adjective as well as a noun. Here's one relevant citation from the OED:

> She takes to the streets daily in response to calls from tenants to
>   investigate nuisance neighbours.

Comment: So you propose I use with civilians? Ignored children grow up to become nuisance citizens?

Comment: @Caffeine: Not necessarily, but you were, as I understand it, asking for an adjectival form of 'nuisance'. In fact, the word which would probably best meet your need is 'antisocial', or perhaps 'disruptive'.

Comment: Perhaps you could just say "ignored children grow up to become nuisances".

Answer (score 4):

*Troublesome* works well.

> The children grow up to become quite troublesome citizens, such as thieves and petty criminals.

Answer (score 2):

The most common adjective for something/someone that's [being] a nuisance is **annoying**.

[In very general terms, a nuisance is something that annoys](http://www.mrsc.org/subjects/legal/nuisances/nu-what.aspx)

(The link is to a "legally-oriented" website answering the question *"What is a Nuisance?"*).

---

I don't think describing psychologically damaged individuals as a "nuisance" is particularly constructive, and most people probably wouldn't say crackheads in Central Park, nationwide paedophile rings, psychopaths, etc. are "annoying".

But you might say it was annoying if someone's kid on the restaurant table next to you was playing a bleeping electronic game, and the parents were ignoring it. I've just answered the question about the normal verb/adjective/adverb for nuisances - they *annoy*, it's *annoying*, they do it *annoyingly*.

Answer (score 2):

We could coin "nuisant", which follows convention and has a pleasing ring.

Comment: Not coin, revive. It appears in OED as obsolete: "Harmful, hurtful; of the nature of a nuisance."

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you could say:

> . . . the children become delinquents.

or

> . . . the children become delinquent citizens.

From *[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/delinquent?region=us&q=delinquent)*:

> **delinquent** |dəˈlɪŋkwənt|
>   *adjective*
>   (typically of a young person or that person's behavior) showing or characterized by a tendency to commit crime, particularly minor crime : *delinquent children*.

Comment: True, perhaps. However, it is the OP's opnion that they become an embarassment/ irritant (nuisance) than criminal (deliquent) -- the connotation in either case, I mean.

Comment: The OP wants to describe children who "grow up to become not-so-constructive citizens, such as thieves and petty criminals." Delinquent is appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just say *nuisancical*?

Comment: Because it's nonsensical?